# using ListAdapter inside a fragment class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm having trouble using a List Adapter inside a Fragment class.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    getActivity().getBaseContext(),
    itemsList,
    R.layout.list_item,
    new String[] {
        TAG_VENDORNAME,
        TAG_PRICE
    },
    new int[] {
        R.id.vendorName, R.id.price
    }
);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Error message is on setListAdapter:

> setListAdapter(adapter) is undefined for the type
>   SearchActivity.SearchFragment.GetResults

`GetResults` is a class i've created for the `AsyncToken` Api call.

I thought `setListAdapter` was a library inside the `ListAdapter` class?

Comment: `setListAdapter` is a method of the `ListActivity` and `ListFragment` classes: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)

Comment: Just add ListView to your fragment and use SimpleAdapter with it (however it's a good idea to subclass ArrayAdapter in order to customize your views)

Comment: @KenWolf This method also exists for `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your fragment extends [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) class, not just `Fragment`. `setListAdapter()` method is defined on `ListFragment` class. Then you need to call this method on the instance of `ListFragment` class.